# "Il (ce) n'est pas" or "il ne s'agit pas"?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, pronoms

What is the difference between

> Il (ce) n'est pas

and

> il ne s'agit pas

and when is appropriate to use one or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« Il n'est pas » et » ce n'est pas » ne sont pas toujours interchangeables. On ne peut employer « il » que si l'objet que le pronom représente quelque chose qui est nommé.

Exemples :

- Ce n'est pas encore cinq heures. Il n'est pas encore cinq heures.
- Ce n'est pas vrai. <del>Il n'est pas vrai.</del>
- Ce n'est pas vrai de dire que la terre se réchauffe. Il n'est pas vrai de dire que la terre se réchauffe.
- Ce n'est pas possible. <del>Il n'est pas possible</del>.
- Ce n'est pas possible de croire ça. Il n'est pas possible de croire ça.

« Il ne s'agit pas de » peut parfois être employé dans le sens de « ce n'est pas » pour désigner quelque chose (il ne s'agit pas + GN).

- Il ne s'agit pas du bon document. Ce n'est pas le bon document.
- Il ne s'agit d'une question d'argent.  Ce n'est pas une question d'argent.

Par contre quand « il ne s'agit pas » ne désigne pas quelque chose mais quand ça veut dire « il n'est pas question de » (il ne s'agit pas + GV) on ne peut pas le remplacer par « ce n'est pas ».

- Il ne s'agit pas de refaire le monde.
- Il ne s'agit pas de discuter pendant des heures.

---

You can't use *Il n'est pas* and *ce n'est pas* indifferently.
"*Il*" can only be used when it represents something that is identified in the sentence.

- *Ce n'est pas encore cinq heures. Il n'est pas encore cinq heures.* It isn't five yet.

*Il ne s'agit pas*  can be replaced by *ce n'est pas* when it is followed by a noun group.

- *Il ne s'agit pas du bon document. Ce n'est pas le bon document.* It isn't the right document.

When *Il ne s'agit pas de* is followed by a verb group we cannot use *ce n'est pas* instead.

- *Il ne s'agit pas de refaire le monde.* It's not about 
  reconstructing the world.
- *Il ne s'agit pas de discuter pendant des heures.* There's no way we're going to discuss this for hours.

Comment: "Ce n'est pas encore cinq heures" bothers me a little : I don't think I ever heard/read it

Comment: PS : however "*Ce n'est pas (encore) l'heure*" seems more ok

Comment: @FredP: It's quite common to say « c'est pas encore X heure » dropping "ne".

Comment: @Laure: For me it isn’t, but I guess it’s a localism issue.

Comment: Mentally translating your example sentences to English, would it be correct to say that « ce n'est pas » can be replaced by « il n'est pas » precisely in the cases where the English "it is not" *cannot* be replaced by "that is not" — that is, when « ce » / "it" serves as a syntactical "virtual subject", as opposed to an actual pronoun referring to something previously stated or understood?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen. I don't think so. Because in English you could have the following conversation: A. "*C'est mardi aujourd'hui*". B- "*C'est (ce n'est) pas vrai, c'est mercredi*." <del>*Il n'est pas vrai*</del> would be impossible. Whereas in English we can say: A- "It's Tuesday today." B- "That's not true/ it's not true, it's Wednesday".

Comment: @Laure: That's exactly what I meant, sorry for expressing it unclearly. Here, in B's sentence, « ce » / "it" refers to the previous claim by A, so it can be replaced by "that" in English but *not* by « il » in French. Conversely, « Il est mardi aujourd'hui. » at least sounds plausible to my (admittedly rather rusty) ear, whereas "\*That's Tuesday today." does not.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: It might well be me who misread your comment. Anyway we agree. I think the use of "ce" vs "il" is difficult to grasp for non natives. If you say  « Il est mardi aujourd'hui. » everyone will understand but a French native would never say it.